# Diving off cliff, a dive meaning please

Tags: meaning

What is the back triple quad? 
It is a dive that Gary Hunt and David Colturi did.
I've already seen videos but I don't get it.

Comment: This isn't English, it's sports (diving in particular). Knowing that "quad" is short for "quadruple" really won't help you understand it much better. Google it.

Comment: I did but I didn't get what "triple quad" means, I saw how they dive it @Peter Shor

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it concerns a usage in a highly specific register, and should be asked on a suitable site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The triple applies to the somersaults; the quad applies to the twists:

> the gold went to Britain’s Gary Hunt, who nailed his “[**back
>   triple-quad**](http://www.washingtonpost.com/sports/olympics/meet-the-extreme-divers-risking-injury-to-win-acceptance-for-their-sport/2015/08/05/1489ec14-3b7b-11e5-9c2d-ed991d848c48_story.html)” — a three-somersault, four-rotation-twist dive from a
>   back-to-the-water position

Comment: [LMGTFY](http://tinyurl.com/qzns4ug)

Comment: @deadrat 
wow you are a life saver!!

Comment: what about the "triple half" dive?

Comment: @FumbleFingers: did you do anything special to add a LMGTFY link? When I tried that some months ago, the website wouldn't accept the link.

Comment: @FumbleFingers oh really? you think that I forgot to google it? am trying to get what "TRIPLE AND QUAD" stand for and I've got the answer now

Comment: I'll probably provoke the ire of the mods if they notice this interchange. I just used [an ad-hoc tiny url](http://tinyurl.com/) to defeat them!

Comment: Triple half dive would be 3 somersaults and half a twist (180 degrees of rotation).